# Image full width in flexbox introducing spacing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a responsive two column element (25% and 75% width), with the height of the element being determined by an image within the left column. My code works, but the height is a few pixels larger than the image - why is that and how can I fix it?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.s3 {
  flex: 25%;
}

.s9 {
  flex: 75%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3" style="background-color: red;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/500">
  </div>
  <div class="col s9" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display:block` to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
.s3{
line-height:0
}
```

this is work!